# How to add a HashMap to the document in the firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add the HashMap "attending" to the .collection("Users").document(user_id) and it seems that .add() does not work with this, so I used .set(), however it erases all the previously stored data on the document(user_id).

How could I just add the fields to the document rather then rewriting the whole document in this case?

```
attending.put(ID,a);

firebaseFirestore.collection("Events").document(ID).collection("Users").add(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {


        //Toast.makeText(eventRegistration.this, "User Stores", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).set(attending).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        Toast.makeText(eventRegistration.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference.html#add(java.lang.Object)) on a CollectionReference. always creates a new document with a random ID.  Calling [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#set(java.lang.Object,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.SetOptions)) on a DocumentReference will overwrite the document, but you can change that by passing a second [SetOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SetOptions.html) type argument that says to merge the new data with the existing data - just call [SetOptions.merge()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SetOptions.html#merge()) to get that object to pass.  [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#update(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) will always just try to update an existing document.

The fact that you're trying to update with a Map doesn't change the way any of these methods work.

All of these operations are also discussed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).